# Toolbar menu does not work anymore

Tags: java, android, toolbar, android-appcompat

I changed from a normal ActionBar to the new Toolbar. My problem is that my old menu doesn't work. When I click on the overflow icon nothing happens. I'm using appcompat v7 but I could not find any solution.
Can someone help me?

Menufunctions:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chatmenu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.onlineliste:
        getOnlineList();
        return true;
    case R.id.settings:
        showSettings();
        return true;
    case R.id.logout:
        logout();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Chatmenu:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
<item 
    android:id="@+id/onlineliste" 
    android:title="@string/userliste"
    app:showAsAction="always">
</item>
<item 
          android:id="@+id/settings" 
          android:title="@string/settings" 
          app:showAsAction="never">
</item>
    <item 
          android:id="@+id/logout" 
          android:title="@string/logout" 
          app:showAsAction="never">
</item>
</menu>
```

Theme

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#428bca</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#428bca</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" />
```

Comment: whats your chatmenu?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to add it. See my edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh my godness I got it. Thank you for all your help guys!
The problem was that I had a RelativeLayout which was overlapping the toolbar but I did not see this directly. THe solution was to add

`android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"` to the relativ layout and now everything works fine.

Again thanks for all your help guys and sorry!

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
<item 
    android:id="@+id/onlineliste" 
    android:visible="true" 
    android:title="@string/userliste" 
    app:showAsAction="never">
</item>
<item 
          android:id="@+id/settings" 
          android:visible="true" 
          android:title="@string/settings" 
          app:showAsAction="never">
</item>
    <item 
          android:id="@+id/logout" 
          android:visible="true" 
          android:title="@string/logout" 
          app:showAsAction="never">
</item>
```

also your theme must have a parent of `Theme.AppCompat` and your Activity must extends from `ActionBarActivity`

Comment: Tried it, nothing changed :/ Yes I already have Theme.AppCompat as a parent

Comment: remove `android:visible="true"`

Comment: still the same behavior, I click on the 3 dots and nothing happens

Comment: replace `return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);` by `return true;`

Comment: still does not open :/

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to set your `Toolbar` as the activity ActionBar, using:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.your_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: Yes I already did `Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }`

Comment: Are you inheriting your theme from a AppCompat.NoActionBar theme?
Also make sure you are using <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar> instead of <android.widget.Toolbar>.

Comment: my parent theme is Theme.AppCompat.Light

Comment: Your theme provides its own ActionBar, so you shouldn't call `setSupportActionBar()`. Or, try switching to `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`.

Comment: Still does not work :/ I need to use setSupportActionBar() for showing it, but the menu still does not show up

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning true from the onCreateOptionMenu().

The documentation says that

```
You must return true for the menu to be displayed; if you return false it will not be shown.
```

Insead of

```
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

which always return false. Return true from onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

Check out the documentation here.
[Source Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29)

Comment: Does not work, mmlooloo mentioned this too
by the way it worked before with the normal actionbar too, so it can't be a requirement to return true all the time